# Shared memory class

Tags: c++, error-handling, linux, c++17, library

I wrote a class that opens a shared memory communication to use in my project, and would like a review.

mylib_com.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef __MYLIB_COM_HPP
#define __MYLIB_COM_HPP

#include <sys/mman.h>   /* For mmap */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* For O_* in shm_open */
#include <unistd.h>     /* For ftruncate and close*/
#include <string.h>     /* For strcpy*/
#include <string>

namespace Myns{
    class Channel{
        public:
            Channel(std::string name, size_t size = sizeof(char)*50);
            ~Channel();
            void write(const char * msg);
            std::string read();
        private:
            int memFd;
            int res;
            u_char * buffer;
    };  
}

#endif
```

mylib_com.cpp

````cpp
#include "mylib_com.hpp"
#include <errno.h>
#include <system_error>

Myns::Channel::Channel(std::string name, size_t size){
    memFd = shm_open(name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    if (memFd == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't open file");
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "Couldn't open shared memory");
    }

    res = ftruncate(memFd, size);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't truncate file");
        close(memFd);
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "Couldn't truncate shared memory");
    }

    buffer = (u_char *) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memFd, 0);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't mmap");
        close(memFd);
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "Couldn't mmap shared memory");
    }
}

Myns::Channel::~Channel(){
    close(memFd);
}

void Myns::Channel::write(const char * msg){
    strcpy((char*)buffer,msg);
}
```
````

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to use `boost::interprocess`?

Comment: Did you forget the `read()` memberfunction?

Comment: Well, I didn`t know I could use boost. Actually never used... For my use i just didn`t need read() right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `__MYLIB_COM_HPP` is a reserved identifier, you're not allowed to use these in your code.
- Instead of including both `<string>` and `<string.h>`, you could also use `std::strcpy()`. Also, you don't need that in the header, move it to the implementation file.
- `sizeof (char)` is by definition one, because `sizeof` gives you the size in multiples of that of a `char`. That part is basically redundant.
- Outputting an error with `perror()` and throwing it as an exception is kind-of redundant as well. If you don't log an error when you catch it, you're a fool or have reason to ignore it, but you can't make that decision at the place where the error occurs.
- You are using C-style casts. Don't, use the C++ casts (`static_cast` in the cases here) instead.
- I'm not sure what `u_char` is, that may not be portable.
- Avoid casting altogether: `mmap()` returns `void*`, which you cast to `u_char*` and store in buffer. In the only case where you use `buffer`, you cast it to `char*` first. Don't, just keep it a `void*` and only cast when you need.
- You have no error checking when writing. You just take the `char const*` and feed it to `strcpy()`, without any bounds check.

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple of additional points...

I've not used c++17, but when performing tests against constants, consider putting the constants on the left, rather than the right.  This prevents typos from having unexpected consequences.  `if (res = -1)` changes the value of `res`, whereas `if(-1 = res)` doesn't compile.

You're keeping variables in your class that seem like they aren't needed.  If they're only needed for the constructor, then use local variables.  Maybe you have other plans for it, but `res` looks particularly suspect, since it's always going to be `0` if the class has been constructed and in the code you've supplied it's never read again.